# why Cakephp view cache doesn't work in host?

Tags: cakephp, caching

In the local host(wamp) Cakephp cache works.

but when I upload it to a real host, it doesn't work.

there is no log error in the files.
and Cache Views folder perm is 0777 .

I'll thank you if you help me.

Comment: Please clarify "works" and "doesn't work".  Are you getting any errors?

Comment: It works just in localhost. but when upload it to a host, it not work. there is no errors (inline error or log error). just it dosn't make cache page in Views folder.

Comment: Have a look here <http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html>, most probably an adaptation in you htaccess is needed for the needs of your host. I also make cakePHP applications on windows and my host is linux. Only the htaccess files are different on both platforms.